# Use parseInt to create wrapper objects

Tags: java, object, wrapper

I’m reading the book  Beginning Java 9 fundamentals  and in relation to creating wrapper objects the author says:

> “All wrapper classes are immutable. They provide three ways to create
>   their objects:

1-Using constructors.

2-Using the `valueOf()` factory methods.

3-Using `parseXxx()` method, where `Xxx` is the name of the wrapper class. It is not available in the `Character` class.

The first and the second point I have clear, but the third I do not finish to understand it completely.
But the API says that Integer.parseXxx returns a primitive.
Does it make any sense?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, these docs may help clear up some of the confusion:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the static method `Integer.parseInt(String)` attempts to parse the given string into a primitive integer. Failing to do that, it will throw an exception.

So basically, there is no need to wrap it, as it guaranteed either succeeding, or "letting you know" it couldn't by throwing.

Comment: But Integer.parseInt(...) for example, itself does not create any object, does it?. Only return a primitive

Comment: It will not create an instance of Integer (boxed primitive), no.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see using `parseXxx` to create a wrapper object is to actually have the target type be a wrapper type itself. i.e:

```
Integer number = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

Yet, *`parseInt` is not really creating a wrapper object* but rather the value returned by `parseInt` is being *autoboxed* to its corresponding wrapper type.

Comment: @silviaDominguez agreed, the wording could definitely be improved.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the **[source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java)** of Integer class confirms that `Integer.parseInt` returns int primitive. Below is how the method signature,

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

The api basically Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, for api to work.

And it can be used as below, in java program, to get the `int` primitive from `String`

```
int newInt = Integer.parseInt("99");
```